# series to rational order

Tags: series-expansion

The function `Series` requires that the expansion order is an integer, i.e. for the input

```
Series[x^(1/4)+x^(1/3)+x^(1/2),{x,0,1/3}]
```

it will give the warning

```
Series::serlim: "Series order specification 1/3 is not a machine-sized integer."
```

and return the `Series` unevaluated.

It seems to me that this is a well defined and easily solvable problem though. In fact, we can write our own series function as follows,

```
mySeries[expr_, {x_, x0_, n_?IntegerQ}] := Series[expr, {x, x0, n}]
mySeries[expr_, {x_, x0_, n_}] :=  Quiet[
Series[ expr /. x -> x^Denominator[n], {x, x0, Numerator[n]}] /. 
 SeriesData[y_, y0_, list_, nmin_, nmax_, nfrac_] :> 
SeriesData[y, y0, list, nmin, nmax, Denominator[n] nfrac], SeriesData::sdatc]
```

Now,

```
mySeries[x^(1/4)+x^(1/3)+x^(1/2),{x,0,1/3}]
```

gives

```
SeriesData[x, 0, {1, 1}, 3, 6, 12]
```

(This is `x^(1/4)+x^(1/3)+O(x^(1/2))`), as expected.

Why is this not the standard behaviour of `Series`, is there something subtle I'm missing, or is this a bug?

Also note that `SeriesCoefficient` works perfectly fine with rational powers.

Comment: It's a limitation. `Series` might give a result with fractional powers but I believe it does not like to see them in the input spec.

Comment: I see, but is there any reason for this limitation? It seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: same with Maple: `series(x^(1/4)+x^(1/3)+x^(1/2), x=0,1/3 );` gives `Error, invalid input: series expects its 3rd argument, n, to be of type {infinity, nonnegint}, but received 1/3`

Answer (score 2):

In general your way may be right, but in the example like yours one can do an easy trick. Let us first replace:

```
  expr = x^(1/4) + x^(1/3) + x^(1/2) /. x -> z^12 // Simplify[#, z > 0] &

(*  z^3 (1 + z + z^3)  *)
```

Then apply `Series`:

```
expr2 = Series[expr, {z, 0, 4}] // Normal

(*  z^3 + z^4  *)
```

Then replace back:

```
    expr2 /. z -> x^(1/12) // Simplify[#, x > 0] &

(*  x^(1/4) + x^(1/3)   *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Hi Alexei, yes indeed, that's precisely what `mySeries` above does, except that it keeps it as a `SeriesData` object to make the output identical to that of `Series`.